# Reference Symfony2 template in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, symfony, twig

I am trying to reference a twig file (mapCities.html.twig), from my main bandle, in a custom directive. Can anyone help me with this?

```
app.directive('customDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'mapCities.html',
    // template: '<div id="sampleCode">This is sample code</div>',
    replace: true
  }
})
```

1. At the moment I am getting an 404 (as expected).
2. My project is in
   Symfony2 & AngularJS

Comment: Angular is a front-end library and thus needs front-end access to the file you're trying to reference. Your `mapCities.html.twig` file is a view file internal to your Symfony app. It must be exposed using some sort of Route -> Controller -> View combo.

Comment: You are right on this. I changed it with an HTML file but still it doesn't work. I just read that the templateURL can optionally contain a DOM element id when the template is defined in <script> tags.

Comment: I understand what `templateUrl` is. You simply can't access a Twig file directly using it.

Comment: We agree on this. I just altered my code so instead of a twig file I am trying to reference an html file. but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Twig views are not directly accessible from the front-end. You must set up a route in `routing.yml` to access the file using the [basic rendering controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html):

```
acme_bundle_map_cities:
    path: /mapCities
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template:    'AcmeBundle:Static:mapCities.html.twig'
```

Then modify your directive to match this route:

```
app.directive('customDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/mapCities',
    // template: '<div id="sampleCode">This is sample code</div>',
    replace: true
  }
});
```

Make sure you modify your values accordingly.

Comment: Fantastic. I wasn't aware of the basic rendering controller. That'll save some boilerplate in future. Thanks.

Comment: You saved my day ! It  worked super astonishingly and amazingly great :)